# Using a string channel box to reference particle object

Tags: expression, maya, mel

I am using an emit command in the `per particle` editor to emit new particles. This expression is in the `per particle` attribute editor of `nParticle1`.

```
$particleName = nParticle2 ;
emit -o $particleName ;
```

My expression works fine. What I am trying to do is I would like to reference `nParticle2` in a string attribute channel box.

I thought I could add a string attribute on `nParticle1`. Name of the attribute : `myNewParticle`.

I tried this in the perParticle attribute editor:

```
$particleName = nParticle1.myNewParticle ;
emit -o $particleName ;
```

But this doesn't work. Also I tried:

```
$particleName = nParticle1.myNewParticle ;
emit -at $particleName ;
```

But it seems that I have to have an object flag.

I would like to be able to access the name of the new particle because I am building a GUI and if the user change the name of the new particle, it is easy to change their name without the need to open the `per particle` attribute editor.

Can someone help me to find the right documentation or know how I could to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can do in single argument but you can try this

`emit -object $particleName -at myNewPartic`le; Check this [doc](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/Commands/emit.html)